# How do I marshall a recursive struct to c sharp?

Tags: c#, marshalling, recursive-datastructures

I have an unmanaged struct I'd like to marshal to c sharp that looks basically like this:

```
struct MyStruct{  
    /* ... some stuff ... */
    int numChilds;  
    MyStruct *childs;
}
```

I believe that I have to write a custom marshaller but I'm not sure on how to proceed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to use a setup like this when I don't need to directly index children:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    /* ... some stuff ... */
    int numChilds;
    IntPtr childData;

    public IEnumerable<MyStruct> Children
    {
        get
        {
            int elementSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct));
            for (int i = 0; i < this.numChilds; i++)
            {
                IntPtr data = new IntPtr(this.childData.ToInt64() + elementSize * i);
                MyStruct child = (MyStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(data, typeof(MyStruct));
                yield return child;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you *do* need to directly index children, the easiest thing is creating a method `GetChild` (shown below). The harder way is creating a helper/wrapper class that implements `IList<MyStruct>`. An instance would be returned from the `Children` property, and its internal would work by calling the `GetChild` method. This is left as an exercise to the reader should he need it.

```
public MyStruct GetChild(int index)
{
    if (index < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index", "The index must be >= 0.");
    if (index >= this.numChilds)
        throw new ArgumentException("The index must be less than the number of children", "index");

    int elementSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct));
    IntPtr data = new IntPtr(childData.ToInt64() + elementSize * index);
    MyStruct child = (MyStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(data, typeof(MyStruct));
    return child;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to pass it to some unmanaged function, you could just use unsafe code and stackalloc / fix an array to get a pointer to the array of objects.

```
        unsafe struct Foo
        {
            public int value;
            public int fooCount;
            public Foo* foos;
        }

        [DllImport("dll_natv.dll")]
        static extern void PrintFoos(Foo f);

        public unsafe static void Main()
        {
            Foo* foos = stackalloc Foo[10];

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
                foos[i].value = i;

            Foo mainFoo = new Foo();
            mainFoo.fooCount = 10;
            mainFoo.value = 100;
            mainFoo.foos = foos;

            PrintFoos(mainFoo);


        }
```